# A problem with play mms streaming

Tags: iphone, streaming

Error log:

```
[Session started at 2009-11-25 11:10:27 +0700.]
2009-11-25 11:10:32.454 MoviePlayer[1085:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid content URL provided to MPMoviePlayerController (mms://202.142.200.130/fm97.5). Use +[NSURL fileURLWithPath:] for local movie files.'
2009-11-25 11:10:32.456 MoviePlayer[1085:207] Stack: (
    31081563,
    2496697609,
    31165499,
    31165338,
    26283790,
    11147,
    16078,
    2733145,
    3140514,
    3149251,
    3144463,
    2838067,
    2746396,
    2773173,
    39177937,
    30866304,
    30862408,
    39171981,
    39172178,
    2777091,
    10648,
    10502
)
```

Code Sample:

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mms://202.142.200.130/fm97.5"];
    MoviePlayerAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MoviePlayerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate initAndPlayMovie:movieURL];


-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL
{
    // Initialize a movie player object with the specified URL
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    if (mp)
    {
        // save the movie player object
        self.moviePlayer = mp;
        [mp release];

        // Apply the user specified settings to the movie player object
        [self setMoviePlayerUserSettings];

        // Play the movie!
        [self.moviePlayer play];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content URL is invalid. I would guess that the `MPMoviePlayerController` class doesn't support MMS (Microsoft Media Server). If you absolutely need support, I see from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server) that [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) supports MMS, so you could try porting that portion of the code over. This is a pretty hard problem to Google around with that *other* defintion of MMS being so prevalent in iPhone discussions.

Comment: I don't have any more details for you. Porting a portion of VLC to the iPhone would be no small issue. Plus you'd have to release your iPhone port under the GPL. Good luck.

Comment: now i'm stick at compling framework VLCKit 
hope it will pass soon

Comment: Hi, have you got the result ? how to play the MMS ? 

 thanks!

Comment: Hey, were you able to play the mms stream